# Hard determinant test problem related to prime numbers: using Fermat's little theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, determinant

The problem is divided into two subproblem, and first problem is to prove FLT. I want to ask for the solution of second one.
Prove or disprove: $$\det{\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & a_2 &\cdots & a_p \\ a_p & a_1 & \cdots & a_{p-1} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_2 & a_3 & \cdots & a_1 \end{pmatrix}} \equiv a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_p \pmod{p}$$ where each $a_i$'s are integers and $p$ is a prime number. Each row of the matrix is obtained by shifting first row rightward.
I can't use induction since it's prime number, not positive integer. How can I give the proof(or counterexample)?

Comment: This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667793/why-are-almost-all-prime-sized-circulant-matrices-non-singular

Comment: That's called "rotating the the row".  Shifting would imply insertion of zeros on the newly opened entry positions and a complete loss of the shifted-off data.

Comment: $$
\det \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ a_2 & a_1 \end{pmatrix} = a_1^2 - a_2^2 = \\ (a_1 + a_2)(a_1 - a_2) = \\ (a_1 + a_2)^2 = \\a_1^2 + 2a_1 a_2 + a_2^2 = \\ a_1 + a_2 \pmod 2 
$$

So it works when $p = 2$.

$$
\det \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ a_3 & a_1 & a_2 \\ a_2 & a_3 & a_1\end{pmatrix} = a_1 (a_1^2 -a_2 a_3) - a_2(a_3 a_1 - a_2^2) +a_3(a_3^2 -a_1a_2) = \\ a_1^3 -a_1a_2a_3 -a_2a_3a_1 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 - a_1 a_2 a_3 = a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3
$$

But plugging in $a_1 = 2, a_2 = 2, a_3 = 1$ gives:  $a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 = 8 + 8 + 1 = 17 = 2 \pmod 3$, etc.  So it seems to be true